# Do I need to Dispose DbContext when using an InMemoryDatabase?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my unit tests I use EF Core 2.2 with an [InMemoryDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/) such as:

```
var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("Foo").Options;
using (var context = new MyContext(dbOptions));
{
    // Do stuff..
}
```

When using `UseInMemoryDatabase` do I really need to dispose the `DbContext`? After reading [Jon Gallants blog](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/) I realize that `Dispose()` isn't *always* needed even when using a real SQL database provider. What is the point of disposing the `DbContext` when using an InMemoryDatabase? Can I leave it to GC?

Comment: Just dispose whats the harm, then future users are'nt doing research looking for bugs and memory leaks when they see and undiposed object that implements IDisposable

Comment: just a small thing - be a little wary of articles that old (`2012-10-04`).  I'm not saying there is anything wrong as such, but as you know we live a fast changing space. I always look for info published within the last 12 months to start with.

Comment: @MichaelRandall - by wrapping the code in a `using` block the disposed gets called automatically for you.

Comment: I am not sure about your question. But I would like to leave Dispose because if to remove Dispose then it is easy to forget about it when you will change MemberyDatabase to any other database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the context has no dependencies like a db connection or file resources that should be freed on dispose, you can leave out the dispose.

All the references that go out of scope get marked for garbage collection automatically.

By the looks of your code you have a `using` block which in my opinion is a good thing because as soon as the running code leaves your `using` block, `Dispose` get called.